# Store object partially in cache

Tags: c#

I want to cache only few property values of an object. I also want this to be configurable in some way.Should I use custom attributes to decorate the properties and resolve this while storing in cache ? Is using reflection going to be expensive, given the cache would be short lived. I am still not able to figure out how to make this thing configurable.

Here is my code

```
public static void GetCacheProperties<T>(T item) where T : new()
{
    var type = item.GetType();

    var properties = item.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        if(property.GetCustomAttributes().Any(u=>u..GetType() == typeof(CustomCacheAttribute)))
        {
           var value = type.GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(item, null);
        }
    }

   //Do I create a new object with just the retrieved property values to store in cache ?
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. What is the bigger picture here? What do you want to achieve? Where is _cache_ stored, created, etc.? What are yout constraints? Which operetions should be fast?

Comment: I am expecting a large collection. The collection item can represent a big object graph. So, when caching the collection I just want to consider certain properties to be stored. I am talking about httpruntime cache or Appfabric cache.